# How do I fix the Return URL in Vtiger appending "?success=ok" to the URL?

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm

VTiger is adding "?success=ok" to the Return URL of my webform. I can't figure out how to fix it. I think the problem is in the below php file.

```
<?php

// Switch the working directory to base
chdir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..');

include_once 'include/Zend/Json.php';
include_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php';
include_once 'include/utils/VtlibUtils.php';
include_once 'include/Webservices/Create.php';
include_once 'modules/Webforms/model/WebformsModel.php';
include_once 'modules/Webforms/model/WebformsFieldModel.php';
include_once 'include/QueryGenerator/QueryGenerator.php';
include_once 'includes/main/WebUI.php';

class Webform_Capture {

function captureNow($request) {
    $currentLanguage = Vtiger_Language_Handler::getLanguage();
    $moduleLanguageStrings =                             Vtiger_Language_Handler::getModuleStringsFromFile($currentLanguage);
    vglobal('app_strings', $moduleLanguageStrings['languageStrings']);

    $returnURL = false;
    try {
        if(!vtlib_isModuleActive('Webforms')) throw new Exception('webforms is not active');

        $webform = Webforms_Model::retrieveWithPublicId(vtlib_purify($request['publicid']));
        if (empty($webform)) throw new Exception("Webform not found.");

        $returnURL = $webform->getReturnUrl();
        $roundrobin = $webform->getRoundrobin();

        // Retrieve user information
        $user = CRMEntity::getInstance('Users');
        $user->id=$user->getActiveAdminId();
        $user->retrieve_entity_info($user->id, 'Users');

        // Prepare the parametets
        $parameters = array();
        $webformFields = $webform->getFields();
        foreach ($webformFields as $webformField) {
            if($webformField->getDefaultValue()!=null){
                $parameters[$webformField->getFieldName()] = decode_html($webformField->getDefaultValue());
            }else{
                $webformNeutralizedField = html_entity_decode($webformField->getNeutralizedField(),ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8");
                if(is_array(vtlib_purify($request[$webformNeutralizedField]))){
                    $fieldData=implode(" |##| ",vtlib_purify($request[$webformNeutralizedField]));
                }
                else{
                    $fieldData=vtlib_purify($request[$webformNeutralizedField]);
                    $fieldData = decode_html($fieldData);
                }

                $parameters[$webformField->getFieldName()] = stripslashes($fieldData);
            }
            if($webformField->getRequired()){
                if(!isset($parameters[$webformField->getFieldName()]))  throw new Exception("Required fields not filled");
            }
        }

        if($roundrobin){
            $ownerId = $webform->getRoundrobinOwnerId();
            $ownerType = vtws_getOwnerType($ownerId);
            $parameters['assigned_user_id'] = vtws_getWebserviceEntityId($ownerType, $ownerId);
        }
        else{
            $ownerId = $webform->getOwnerId();
            $ownerType = vtws_getOwnerType($ownerId);
            $parameters['assigned_user_id'] = vtws_getWebserviceEntityId($ownerType, $ownerId);
        }

        // Create the record
        $record=vtws_create($webform->getTargetModule(), $parameters, $user);

        $this->sendResponse($returnURL, 'ok');
        return;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->sendResponse($returnURL, false, $e->getMessage());
        return;
    }
}

protected function sendResponse($url, $success=false, $failure=false) {
    if (empty($url)) {
        if ($success) $response = Zend_Json::encode(array('success' => true, 'result' => $success));
        else $response = Zend_Json::encode(array('success' => false, 'error' => array('message' => $failure)));

        // Support JSONP
        if (!empty($_REQUEST['callback'])) {
            $callback = vtlib_purify($_REQUEST['callback']);
            echo sprintf("%s(%s)", $callback, $response);
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
    } else {
        $pos = strpos($url, 'http');
        if($pos !== false){
            header(sprintf("Location: %s?%s=%s", $url, ($success? 'success' : 'error'), ($success? $success: $failure)));
        }else{
            header(sprintf("Location: http://%s?%s=%s", $url, ($success? 'success' : 'error'), ($success? $success: $failure)));
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
// NOTE: Take care of stripping slashes...
$webformCapture = new Webform_Capture();
$webformCapture->captureNow($_REQUEST);
?>
```

I know this is probably really easy but I am not familiar enough with PHP to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: look at those 2 `header()` calls

Comment: When I remove the "($success? 'success' : 'error')" and the other success message behind it the URL doesn't work at all. Brings me to a blank page.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. After Location: I added the correct return url and removed all the other parameters. So "Location: http://www.example.com");

Answer (score 0):

Change capture.php as the following

Around line 104-108 replace:

```
    if($pos !== false){
        header(sprintf("Location: %s?%s=%s", $url, ($success? 'success' : 'error'), ($success? $success: $failure)));
    }else{
        header(sprintf("Location: http://%s?%s=%s", $url, ($success? 'success' : 'error'), ($success? $success: $failure)));
    }
```

with following:

```
    if($pos !== false){
        header(sprintf("Location: %s", $url));
    }else{
        header(sprintf("Location: http://%s", $url));
    }
```